# IconLevel and startForeground

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

I would like to animate the icon of the app **without having to cancel the notification** and create a new one (because in this way the icon doesn't stay in the same position of the notification bar but could move to first place if there are other notification running).

I'm able to get this with normal notification, but I would like to get the same behaviour when  I use startForeground in my service. This method launches a new notification which can't be removed unless you remove service from foreground using stopForeground.

Is this possible to do? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same notification ID for the startForeground method and the Notification object.

Comment: Yes, using the same notification ID will cause the notification to be replaced. But repeatedly replacing the notification is not the way to animate its icon. Instead, create an animation-list in res/drawable and use that as your notification's icon.